# How to set a file as the output in a loader instead of a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, encoding

I have a set up where a few lines of JavaScript loads a text string into a div, but I would like to now load an image instead, I have tried encoding the file path, but it simply renders the file path as a text string, which lets me know I am encoding it incorrectly.

Here is the line of code that currently loads the text.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var perfecto = new Perfecto.App('scene', 'img/map.png');

  perfecto.setLinks([
    {"text": "Loose Lips", "url": "song1.html"},
    {"text": "F&ck What You Say", "url": "song2.html"},
    {"text": "I Love It", "url": "song3.html"},
    null,
    {"text": "No Diamonds (w Yogi B)", "url": "song4.html"},
    {"text": "Stay True", "url": "song5.html"},
    {"text": "What's Up", "url": "news.html"},
    {"text": "Photos", "url": "photos.html"},
    {"text": "Contact", "url": "contact.html"}
  ]);

  // Set logo text and position
  perfecto.setLogo(3, 'Dro$ki');
</script>
```

but of course that only rendered out *img/path-to-path.png* as a text string.

What am I doing wrong? I have researched "how to load a file instead of a string" but it doesn't give me what I want to learn...not on the first 5 google SERP pages, anyway.

Thanks for attention

Comment: Just show `<img src="path/to/image.png">`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). At best, it's a problem of encoding the information or escaping the html.

Comment: no, because the element is actually dynamically created as well.
It uses an image as a background and 9 separate divs to dynamically put stuff into

Comment: sorry Bergi...wrong term. encoding it is. I stand corrected, thanks

Comment: Show us that code that creates the element (presumably the `setLogo` function?). We cannot answer this without knowing what you are doing. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Bergi - post edited to show the code.
The page is here: http://clients.runningh20.com/droski/2/ (See the fourth block where it says "Dro$ki", I would rather it output an image instead)

Comment: [A link doesn't help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1048572), you need to provide the implementation of `Perfecto.App` and its `setLogo` method.

Comment: why? My question is simply to get this code perfecto.setLogo(3, 'Dro$ki');
to put out an image (i.e. - how to encode a file path rather than a string)

That's all I want

Comment: We can't tell you. It could be (and is very likely) that it's impossible even and this function only shows strings (and a file path *is* a string - there is no way to pass some value that magically becomes an image) - you would need to modify the function. If you didn't write that function but instead it is part of some common framework/library, link its documentation at least.

Comment: yeah I'll have to get my hands a little dirty and figure that out. Not so so swift w JS.